# Can 'for' additionally mean 'so that' in some contexts?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I stumbled upon a phrase along the lines of:

> the results are general enough for all participants will be able to reason about them

Is the phrase correct? I'm pretty sure it should be correct (reputable source), but I don't understand its structure; does 'for' here have its standard meaning + something like a 'so that' meaning?

Or otherwise how should I grammatically/syntactically interpret the phrase?

Answer (score 3):

The [**for**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/for) can be used as a *conjunction* to mean **since** or **because** (in a literary style) and if that was the intention there should be a comma before it.

> The results are general enough, for all participants will be able to reason about them.

The sentence could have a different typo error though, and should be

> The results are general enough for all participants ***to*** be able to reason about them.

In the second example, **for** is used as a *preposition*.

As asked in the question, **for** can also mean "so that":

> The results are general enough **so that** all participants will be able to reason about them.